# Send data from servlet to model

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, servlet-3.0

Im trying to input a value in jsp then multiply the input in my model and then set a new attribute and send it to another jsp page.

**Servlet**

```
    String randomNumber = request.getParameter("randomNumber");
    double dbRandomNumber = Integer.parseInt(randomNumber);

    Model m = new Model();

    m.setRandomNumber(dbRandomNumber);
    request.setAttribute("result", m.getResult());
```

**Model**

```
Model class { 
double RandomNumber = 0.0;
double Result = RandomNumber*130;
//getter setters 
}
```

**JSP number 2**

```
//
Result : ${result}
//Doing this works fine: <%= request.getParameter("randomNumber")%>
```

So I feel it get lost somewhere in servlet or model. 
Cant you do like this `m.setRandomNumber(dbRandomNumber);`?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get in JSP number 2: `Result : 0.0`?

Comment: I get nothing thats the problem. Its just "Result:" nothing else.

Comment: Do you know If I need to save it to a session?

Comment: How do you call this jsp?